Compare dataframe with list
I've a script that try to reach some router on the field (from a list in csv), then write a result csv file.
My script have an early condition that check if there is an existing "result.csv" file, and look into it which router is "offline", then make a list from it.
Now I'm trying to compare the first column of a dataframe with all the routers (133 rows), and a list that contain the name (string) of every router that failed to response in the first place.
Here an example of the router list :
       sta          pwd
0    allev          aer
1     alpe          qs   
2     arg1          gre 
3     arg2          dfg   
4     argg          yui

       

(field "sta" is the router name and "pwd" its password.
Then a example of the "toreach" list made from the result file created on the first pass :
['arg1',
 'argg']

Routers that are marked as "offline" in the resultat.csv file, are reported as "toreach" and are appended in the list above. From there I want to compare router list to update it by delete string that are not in the "toreach" list.
Can we use list to compare with dataframe ? Should made a "fake" dataframe with the list ?

out = df.loc[df['sta'].isin(toreach)]

Ho, that's pretty short and effective, and that's actually works. thanks ! Pass your comment in response so I can commit it as the good one.
Or, as I just read above my question that there is already a response to that, I can simply delete it : your opinion ?
